# Are there any laws of other countries similar to the Taiwan Relations Act (1979) of the United States?

Tags: china, taiwan

The G7 has made a joint declaration of support (2023 July) for Ukraine towards...

> Ensuring a sustainable force capable of defending Ukraine now and
> deterring Russian aggression in the future, through the continued
> provision of: security assistance and modern military equipment,
> across land, air, and sea domains – prioritizing air defense,
> artillery and long-range fires, armored vehicles, and other key
> capabilities, such as combat air, and by promoting increased
> interoperability with Euro-Atlantic partners;  support to further
> develop Ukraine’s defense industrial base;  training and training
> exercises for Ukrainian forces; intelligence sharing and cooperation;
> support for cyber defense, security, and resilience initiatives,
> including to address hybrid threats.

[link to the source](https://www.pm.gc.ca/en/news/statements/2023/07/12/g7-joint-declaration-support-ukraine)

Although the declaration comes from a group of countries, the G7, this declaration calls for each country to work with Ukraine towards the declared goals.

This is motivated by the "the strategic objective of a free, independent, democratic, and sovereign Ukraine".

Under the assumption that similar objectives exist for Taiwan, this new declaration of collective action in the case of Ukraine would make the absence of similar commitments for Taiwan marginally harder to justify.

The **Taiwan Relations Act (1979)** requires the United States to make available “such defence articles and defence services in such quantity as may be necessary to enable Taiwan to maintain a sufficient self-defence capability”.

Are there any countries that have something similar to the U.S **Taiwan Relations Act** of 1979 in the way of improving the military capabilities of Taiwan?

[link to Taiwan Relations Act of 1979, United States](https://www.congress.gov/bill/96th-congress/house-bill/2479)

Comment: You should set out what aspects of the 1979 Taiwan Relations Act you are interested in. I'm not sure why you are going on about Ukraine - are you asking if commitments to Ukraine match the Taiwan act?

Comment: @StuartF  I posted an edit that clarifies.   Regarding "going on about Ukraine", it seems there is a parallel situation where an authoritarian government is threatening the freedom and institutions of another people and territory. I'm asking if any  countries other than the U.S. have a law to improve the military capabilities of Taiwan in the way the G7 is now committing to doing for Ukraine.

Comment: I agree that the tangent about Ukraine is unnecessary for understanding the question and makes it read like agenda pushing.

Comment: Voting not to close - The question is pointing out that G7 - a group of countries - have made certain commitments to Ukraine, somewhat similar to what the US had done for Taiwan. And OP is asking if other countries, apart from the US, have also made similar commitments. This can be factually answered.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not a law as such (recall that that law came into being [with a veto-proof majority] because of the US constitutional unclarities about whom can cancel US defense treaties), but besides the US, France has also sold some arms to Taiwan in the 1990s, including artillery (TRF-1s), Lafayette frigates, and Mirage jets.

Although no such sales have occurred recently [that I'm aware of], France [has](https://www.france24.com/en/20200513-china-warns-france-against-selling-weapons-to-taiwan) reaffirmed the right to make such sales to Taiwan as recently as 2020, while at the same time mentioning the year (1994) when they kinda signed up to a one-China policy, something the US also does now and then; the "one China" policy means different things to different people. (Having said this the EU and France have substantially more commercial/business interests in mainland China these days compared to the dwindling US ones.)

And I could not tell you exactly what parts this involved, but news in March [was](https://www.reuters.com/world/uk/uk-approves-increased-submarine-related-exports-taiwan-risking-angering-china-2023-03-13/) that

> The value of licences granted by the British government to companies for the export of submarine-related components and technology to Taiwan totalled a record 167 million pounds ($201.29 million) during the first nine months of last year, according to UK government export licensing data.

While we're at comparisons, no country [officially] has a defense treaty with Ukraine either... And I'm not sure any have any laws that require them to arm Ukraine as such in the long run, although the US appropriations probably have some wording to that effect, at least for the money already allocated.